# Custom ArrayAdapter Filtering for ListView issue when only 1 data show

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, filter, filtering

Suppose I have 4 data in arraylist:
alex
black
chocolate
dark

when I input text to filtering it 'c', the listview displaying "alex", not *chocolate*.
I tried many times and here is my conclusion about my code:
'whenever i tried to search word that only display 1 result, listview will always show the first array of arraylist'
Please help :(

Here is my adapter:

```
public class PesertaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
public ArrayList<String> items;
public ArrayList<String> filtered;
private int layoutResourceId;
private Context context;
private Filter filter;

public PesertaAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> items) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.filtered = items;
    this.items = (ArrayList<String>) items.clone();

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public final TextView tvPeserta;
    public final ImageButton mBtnDelete;

    public ViewHolder (View view) {
        tvPeserta = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        mBtnDelete = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDel);
    }
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    final String s = items.get(position);
    viewHolder.tvPeserta.setText(s);
    viewHolder.mBtnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "isi: " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return row;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(filter == null){
        filter = new PesertaFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}

private class PesertaFilter extends Filter{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            synchronized (this) {
                list.addAll(items);
            }
            results.values = list;
            results.count = list.size();
        }else{
            String prefixString = constraint.toString();
            ArrayList<String> filt = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> lItems = new ArrayList<>();
            synchronized (this) {
                lItems.addAll(items);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < lItems.size(); i++) {
                final String value = lItems.get(i);
                Log.d("ASD", "VALUE: " + value);
                if (value.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                    Log.d("ASD", "VALUEMATCH: " + value);
                    filt.add(value);
                }
            }
            results.values = filt;
            results.count = filt.size();
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filtered = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        if (results.count > 0) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for(int i = 0; i<results.count; i++){
                Log.d("ASD", "FILTERED: " + filtered.get(i));
                add(filtered.get(i));
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        } else {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            add("Not found");
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I log the result in array list (variable name='filtered'), I saw the correct result, but it display wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
final String s = items.get(position);
```

By

```
final String s = getItem(position);
```

Comment: I have change the code but still same output, the problem still exists, I don't know what the mistake that I made, but I think it's in adapter getView?

Comment: still this error drive me crazy haha..
Here is the screenshot:
[link]https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-RkAOh3PUaQM/VJvVjRxTYqI/AAAAAAAAEhA/-wc6fNZBA0o/w856-h1426-no/Screenshot_2014-12-25-16-13-33.jpg

Comment: @JeffersonSetiawan Please upload your sample project to somewhere (dropbox, github, etc) I'll check it

Comment: thank you very much @gio, here is the link in gdrive https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2tdtMd_zg2OYTBHNG5hR3JfVDg/view?usp=sharing
very appreciate your help.